# Close process gracefully that has no window

Tags: windows-7, bash, powershell

So, I have a script that starts some auto-hotkey scripts while also starting up a game. I want those scripts to close again when the game ends. Currently I'm doing this with the `kill` command. This however will keep the icon in my system tray until I hover over it.

I am trying to find a way to remove the icon without me having to hover over it by closing the script gracefully rather than a kill command.

The current script I have:

```
$hotkey = Start-Process PoEHotkeys.exe -PassThru
Start-Process PathOfExile.exe -Wait
$hotkey.Kill()
```

The functions `Close()` and `CloseMainWindow()` do not work on this item since it does not have any window. To manually shut down the script, you normally right click on the icon and press 'Exit'. This does not have to be a solution in Powerscript. It just happens to be the one I'm currently using.

Comment: Are you looking for `stop-process –force` instead of `kill`?

Comment: Also, use `ie4uinit.exe -show` to refresh the taskbar (Windows 10). < Windows 10 use: `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect `-force` to help. Strangely, if I start up 2 scripts, 1 always keeps in my tray while the other disappears correctly. Comment either of the 2 out and it works. Any idea how this happens? Refreshing the tray also doesn't help. Good tip though :)

Comment: Did you try to use `taskkill /im notepad2.exe`. (With your PID, or process..)? When done with notepad for example, the program can even ask to save the current file... Look the [manual](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true). If it works for you I can write down as answer.

Comment: @Didi... Without seeing your full code example I would only guess that your keeping reference to only 1 instance of your script and there for when you stop it your only stopping that instance and not the other. So... If you post more code i could look into it?

Comment: @Hastur `tskill` is not available on on my version of Windows 7. (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit)

Comment: @DavidPostill I have both `tskill` and `taskkill` in the virtual machine with Windows 7 (Windows 7 Enterprise - Service pack 1 - 32 bit)...(bha!)

Comment: @Hastur Apparently it's not in Pro either [tskill in windows 7 versions](http://superuser.com/q/417534)

Comment: @DavidPostill Did you tried `taskkill`? It [seems it should be present](http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm) in the pro version...